# AWS S3 safe from request attack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've just set up an S3 account, Free Tier (Only need it for a few months anyway), and it gives you 20,000 GETS a month.

Currently I don't have good caching in place so its possible that each visitor can rack up 10-20 requests. Now this is only a personal site so I doubt I'll receive the traffic to reach the 20,000.

**What would happen if my site were accessed via some loop that intentionally tried to put a strain on it?** Well, the requests would potentially far exceed 20,000 and I would be left with an un-payable amazon bill through no fault of my own.

Is this something I should be concerned about? I have an alert which sends if I near my limit, but worse case and the above were to happen, am I basically screwed and left in hideous debt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this could happen and it would be difficult for AWS to differentiate between the legitimate requests and false ones.

Therefore it is not a good practice to expose S3 publically without any access control mechanisms.

When you are hosting a website or serving files from S3, you can setup AWS CloudFront to serve the files from S3 also attaching AWS WAF to CloudFront. This way you should be able to do rate limiting and prevent certain attacks.

Comment: I see. Although I suspect they'd be able to tell its an attack. A from my server logs, and B from the fact I'm one person with no interest in pulling people to my little website (besides potential employers) . I would hope and imagine they'd be able to differentiate and use common sense. So my S3 isn't publicly exposed directly, but my PHP will fetch data from S3 through an ajax GET. I think i'm small enough to worry about it. However, I guess if I get concerned, I can implement daily caching. Things don't update enough to worry about every request being fresh.